# Getting 400 error with multiple request in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, http-status-code-400, bad-request

I am requesting for an endpoint which actually creates a task so when I am trying to execute my jmeter script with 500 threads then I am facing some issue. For first 200 threads I am getting 200 response and after that I am getting 400 Bad Request error with the same end point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you check the status of your web server?
There are possibility that web server's connection pool is full.

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTTP Status Code 400 documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400)

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

So I would recommend:

1. Double checking your request details (url, parameters, etc.) using i.e. [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener
2. Check [jmeter.log](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) file for any suspicious entries
3. Review your test configuration, for instance if you use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) which is set not to recycle at the end of file you will be sending `<EOF>` instead of real values which will not be accepted by the server
4. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) as it might be the case JMeter cannot conduct more than 200 virtual users load due to lack of resources